# Sphinx malformed table

Tags: python-sphinx

We've got a RST table in sphinx that looks like this:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Key                     | Appearance in the administration            | Value                                   |
+=========================+=============================================+=========================================+
| |text_line|             | simple text input                           | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |text_area|             | text area                                   | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |text_editor|           | text editor with formatting capabilities    | HTML string                             |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |checkbox|              | checkbox                                    | boolean                                 |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |single_select|         | list of radio buttons                       | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |multiple_select|       | list of checkboxes                          | array of strings                        |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |color|                 | color picker                                | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |date|                  | date picker                                 | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |time|                  | text input with time validation             | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |url|                   | text input with URL validation              | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |email|                 | text input with email validation            | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |password|              | password input                              | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |phone|                 | text input for a phone number               | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |internal_links|        | widget for selecting links to other pages   | resolved pages as defined in parameters |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |single_internal_link|  | widget for selecting a single page          | resolved page as defined in parameters  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |smart_content|         | widget for configuring a data source        | resolved pages as defined in parameters |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |resource_locator|      | widget for entering the URL of a page       | string                                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |tag_list|              | autocomplete input for entering and adding  | array of strings                        |
|                         | tags                                        |                                         |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |category_list|         | autocomplete input for entering and adding  | array of strings                        |
|                         | tags                                        |                                         |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |media_selection|       | widget for selecting media (images,         | array containing arrays with            |
|                         | documents)                                  | urls for every format                   |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |contact_selection|     | widget for selecting contacts               | array containing array representations  |                                     |
|                         |                                             | of the contact objects                  |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| |snippet|               | widget for selecting snippets               | array containing array representations  |
```

|                         |                                             | of the snippets                         |
    +-------------------------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+

Since recently I get the following error when trying to build the documentation using `make build`:

```
ERROR: Malformed table.
```

It also outputs this table again, but without any hint what is wrong here, and I can't find it. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Is there any tool that will pinpoint exactly which line and character where the error exists?

Answer (score 1):

While trying to format the code correctly I found the error on my own... The row for `contact_selection` contained a pipe at the very end of the line, after some tabs...

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the issue was invisible to the human eye, but the problem was mixed use of spaces and tabs.

In your editor-of-choice, do a "find" for spaces and then for tabs. Or try changing the "tab spaces" (the number of spaces that a tab appears as) to make the issue visible.